# Calculating two variables that hold input data and outputting it

Tags: javascript, html

I think this is a simple fix but I cannot for the life of me seem to think about why this isn't working.

I'm a complete novice at JavaScript and HTML as you can probably tell by the code below but I just want it to be functional so I can learn by it.

The goal is to take two of the input values (what the user puts into those boxes specifically) and then divide and multiply that value with a specific integer that doesn't change and output the result into a paragraph.

```
function calculateValues(){
let pretext = document.getElementById("preresults");
let userinput = document.getElementById("results");
let userdistanceboxinput = document.getElementById("distancebox").innerText;
let userfuelboxinput = document.getElementById("fuelinputbox").innerText;
let oneimperialgallontolitre = 4.546;
let oneimperialgallontous = 1.201;

userinput.style.visibility = 'visible';
pretext.style.visibility = 'visible';

userinput = (userdistanceboxinput / userfuelboxinput) * 4.544;
```

The function is tied to an onclick event on a submit button as follows:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitbutton" onclick="calculateValues()" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a value in Javascript, you can do this:

```html
<input type="number" id="input1">
```

```js
const input1 = document.getElementById('input1'); // retrieve the HtmlInputElement
const value1 = input1.target.value; // retrieve the value of this element
```

If you want to set a HtmlInputElement value you can do (same html):

```js
const input1 = document.getElementById('input1'); // retrieve the HtmlInputElement
input.target.value = value1 * 21545 // set value of HtmlInputElement
```

Comment: Ahh I just realised that my attribute for my input tags are "text" and not "number". That could also be another reason why this is not working.

Comment: If you want to convert your string (ex: "2") in a number (ex: 2) you can use the function `parseInt("2")`